# Java iterator, store the values in a object

Tags: java, oop, iterator

please see the below code

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){
   Cell cell=iterator.next();
}
```

When I execute the code iterator has iterate over a excel sheet has 3 columns and returns the value in cell object. My question is that How do I store the 3 column values in a Object which has Customer name, phone, email.

```
Customer{
PhoneNumber;
Name;
email;
}
```

so I need to store the first value from cell in PhoneNumber and second value from cell in Name and third value from cell in email...

Comment: Don't write a loop.  Write explicitly: `phoneNumber = iterator.next(); name = iterator.next(); email = iterator.next();`

Comment: The example code you provided isn't valid or complete. Please review the rules before posting.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks louis wasserman. but i need to read n number of row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Louis mentioned, it is better to call `next` 3 times within loop

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){
   phoneNumber = iterator.next(); 
   name = iterator.next(); 
   email = iterator.next();

   // A new customer object would be created in each iteration 
   Customer cust = new Customer(email, name, phoneNumber);

   // now process customer object here
}
```

Here, in each loop, you will be getting all 3 columns values.